# subquery with in a trigger for multiple rows

Tags: triggers, subquery

I get an error when inserting into the client table I know where the error is, in the subquery but have no idea the work around
- the error I get is *This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression*

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[TRclientpaytype] 
           on [dbo].[Client] 
           for insert
           As
           Beging
              Declare @clientID int
              , @isemployer bit= 1 
              , @isemployee bit=0
              , @createdby varchar(254)= 'Adj'
              , @creationdate smalldatetime= getdate()
              , @Modifiedby varchar(254)= 'Adj'
              , @modifieddate smalldatetime= getdate()
              , @paytype_external varchar(50)= 'Null'
                   Select @clientID=I.clientID from inserted I
        Insert into dbo.ClientPayType
            (
                --[ClientPayTypeID], 
                [ClientID], 
                [PayTypeID], 
                [IsEmployer], 
                [IsEmployee], 
                [CreatedBy], 
                [CreationDate], 
                [ModifiedBy], 
                [ModifiedDate], 
                [PayType_External]
                --[LedgerCode], 
                --[LedgerName]

                )
                VALUES ( @clientID,(select PaytypeID from dbo.PayType where clientID is NULL),@isemployer,@isemployee,@createdby,@creationdate,@Modifiedby,@modifieddate,@paytype_external)

        END
```

Comment: - first time creating a trigger, first time posting. For every new insert into the *client* table that **clientID** is inserted into *clientpaytype* along with multiple rows from the *paytype* table where **clientID** is null, and some hard coded variables in the declare .